# Add X's within certain positions of a multifasta file

Tags: python, biopython, fasta

I have a file with multiple FASTA sequences such as:

**File1.fa**

```
>seq1
AAATTTTTATATACCCTACCATTACCATTACCATTACCATTACCATTACCATTACCATTTTATTATTATTATATACCACACA
>seq2
AAATTTTTATATACCCTACCATTACCATTACCATTACCATTACCATTACCATTACCATTTTATTATTATTATATACCACACA
```

And I have a table such as:

**tab**

```
Seq positions 
seq1 3:10
seq2 10:20,45:60
```

And I would like for each tab['Seq'] to replace letters by a **X**  for each corresponding `seqn` positions within ***File1.fa***

As you can see for the second row, I can have multiple positions to replace (these positions are separated by `,` in the `tab['positions']` column.

Here I should then get a **new_File1.fa** such as:

```
>seq1
AAXXXXXXXXATACCCTACCATTACCATTACCATTACCATTACCATTACCATTACCATTTTATTATTATTATATACCACACA

>seq2
AAATTTTTAXXXXXXXXXXXATTACCATTACCATTACCATTACCXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXTATTATTATTATATACCACACA
```

where for `seq1` I replace **X** from positions 3 to 10, and for `seq2` I replaced **X** from positions 10 to 20 and from positions 45 to 60 positions.

I guess using biopython package should be a solution here?

So far I tried the following:

```
record_dict = SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse("File1.fa, "fasta"))

import re 
for index, row in tab.iterrows():
 start= re.sub(":*.","",row['positions'])
 end= re.sub(".*:","",row['positions'])
 print(record_dict[Seq].seq[start-end])
```

But as you can see I only manage to extract the part I want to replace with X and I cannot figure out how to take into account when there are multiple positions to replace in the sequence.

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: I added what I tried so far ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the sequences to lists, replace your chosen ranges then covert back to a string. For example,

```
seq = "AAABBBCCC"
s = list(seq)

for idx in range(3, 6):
    s[idx] = "X"

new_seq = ''.join(s)    
print(new_seq)
```